# Extracting a string from a string in linux

Tags: linux, shell

Extract the value for OWNER in the following:

```
{{USERID 9898}}{{OWNER Wayne, Daniel}}{{EMAIL danielwayne@blah.com}}
```

To get this string I am using grep on a text file. In all other cases only one value is contained on each line, so they are not an issue.
My problem is removing the text after OWNER but before the }} brackets, leaving me with only the string 'Wayne, Daniel'.

So far I have began looking into writing a for loop to go through the text a character at a time, but I feel there is a more elegant solution then my limited knowledge of unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `grep`

```
> cat file
{{USERID 9898}}{{OWNER Wayne, Daniel}}{{EMAIL danielwayne@blah.com}}

> grep -Po '(?<=OWNER )[\w, ]*' file
Wayne, Daniel
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `cat file.txt | perl -n -e'/OWNER ([^\}]+)/ && print $1'`

Comment: returns a single quote. I haven't used perl yet, I will look into that.

Comment: If there are multiple matches, this will concatenate them. Also `cat` is not required here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F '{{|}}' '{sub(/OWNER +/, "", $4); print $4}' file
Wayne, Daniel
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I use cut

```
INPUT="{{USERID 9898}}{{OWNER Wayne, Daniel}}{{EMAIL danielwayne@blah.com}}"
SUBSTRING=`echo $INPUT| cut -d' ' -f3`
SUBSTRING2=`echo $INPUT| cut -d',' -f2`
SUBSTRING2=`echo $SUBSTRING2| cut -d'}' -f1`
echo $SUBSTRING$SUBSTRING2
```

maybe is not the most elegant way but works.